# How to remove the default UIMenuItem from the UIMenuController in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to remove some default UIMenuItem objects like "Cut", "Copy", etc, from the UIMenuController.

How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass the view that's presenting the menu (eg. `UIWebView`, `UITextView`) and override `-canPerformAction:withSender:` to return `NO` for the menu items you don't want to appear.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
}
```

Comment: How'd you get rid of Paste option? I tried the same with Paste, but it's showing up. I guess, it's because the Paste board has some content already..

Answer (score 0):

```
class TextView: UITextView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

#### In Swift 4 ,

[image: 0]

As Peter Stuart said:
Subclass the view that's presenting the menu (eg. UITextView)

then `override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

return false for the menu items you don't want to appear.