# Removing default cut, copy, paste from UIMenuController in a TableView

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to remove the default menu items from UIMenuController.  I found this post for UIWebview or UITextView:

[How to remove the default UIMenuItem from the UIMenuController in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074694/how-to-remove-the-default-uimenuitem-from-the-uimenucontroller-in-ios)

I'm trying to do this for the new iOS 5 methods where you can show a menu item on the table selection.  So my class is a subclass of UIViewController that has a UITableView in it.  I wasn't sure how or IF removing the default items was possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The table view delegate method `-tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` is for this purpose exactly.

Here is an example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    switch action {
    case Selector("cut:"), Selector("copy:"), Selector("paste:"):
        return false // as per your question
    case Selector("myAction:"):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Use this code to remove the default features of `cut`, `copy`, `paste` and `select`:

```
(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    UIMenuController * menuContoller=[UIMenuController sharedMenuController];    
    if (menuContoller) 
    {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible=NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```