# How to remove UIMenuController item in swift?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I want remove UIMenuController item.

#### This textfield is not a UITextField.

#### That textfield is UIWebView's textfield. Not owned native.

And I tried this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = false
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

But result is always same. How to remove UIMenuItem??

I want only "copy" button. How can I do that??

[image]

Comment: So the textView is not native . It is HTML

Answer (score 3):

To remove UIMenuController item in swift4:

```
class DNGWebView: WKWebView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            return false
    }
}
```

As [Peter Stuart said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074694/how-to-remove-the-default-uimenuitem-from-the-uimenucontroller-in-ios/51356742#51356742): Subclass the view that's presenting the menu (eg. UITextView)

then `override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

return false for the menu items you don't want to appear.

To illustrate it intuitively:

```
import WebKit

class DNGWebView: WKWebView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 11]

Comment: I'm using in UIWebView. Not a WKWebView. If it does not matter, I do not work like you. All the menus are always open ...

Comment: @allanWay, exactly what you said. WKWebView is OK. UIWebView is as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom menu items with action and assign to you UIMenuViewController by following code:

```
let menuCustom1 = UIMenuItem(title: "Custom 1", action: #selector(<MethodName>))
let menuCustom2 = UIMenuItem(title: "Custom 2", action: #selector(<MethodName>))
let menuCustom3 = UIMenuItem(title: "Custom 3", action: #selector(<MethodName>))

UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = true
UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [menuCustom1, menuCustom2, menuCustom3]
UIMenuController.shared.update()
```

**Output:**

[image: UIMenuController custom items]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have already tried that method. The method only adds items. It does not change or remove the original item.

Comment: same result...See that https://imgur.com/a/rvw3Cip ////// https://imgur.com/a/CV10pT1